# How to prevent transaction locking in sql server for all the connections?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

**Hello**

I have a **Sql Server Database** that is accessed from two different applications, one of these application just Select from the Database (lets name it **x**) and the other one (name it **y**) is doing everything.
My problem here is while the y application is inserting or updating the database through a transaction the x application is not able to read from the database.

I'v read about transaction isolation level and found that the **SNAPSHOT** isolation level would be good for my case, but I don't know how to make the default isolation level for the database is SNAPSHOT so that I don't have to specify the isolation level for every transaction or every connection.

**In a nutshell:** *I want to read from the database through an application while there is a transaction from a different application is running.*

**Thanks**

Comment: This sounds more like a resource issue rather that a database issue peruse.  If both databases are independent from each other, the only (main) reason of database x is not responding is a lack of resources, be it processing time or disk access.  This can be an issue of missing indexes on database a, or an anemic server that has excessive drive wait times, low memory, etc…  If the databases interact with each other see below answers about isolation settings.

Comment: I'm sorry sir you miss understood me. I don't have two different databases, I have two different applications(x and y) dealing with the same database.

Comment: Yea, I miss read the question.

Comment: With that in mind, M.Ali has a great point. If the data doesn't have to be 100% up to date, breaking the data into transaction database and reporting database might solve the issue without the issues.  Then porting over the relevant information to the reporting server via replication, batch ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to read the last committed data to the disk, if data is being modified Snapshot Isolation is a good solution.

You can enable snapshot isolation by executing the following command.

```
ALTER DATABASE Database_Name 
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
GO
```

Mind it, it will use your Temp db extensively, make sure your Tempdb is on a drive with plenty of free space.

On the other hand if Application A only reads then you might look into a different solution, like having altogether a separate database for reads only, you can have Log-shipping set to have a read-only copy of that database or maybe Database Replication.

Comment: First thanks for the reply,
But the query you provided isn't working it keeps running in ssms without any output just like if there is a transaction or so. 

Another question if this query worked should I just execute it once at the database or I have to execute it every time I connect to the database?

Comment: It keeps running probably because your database is in use, Make sure there is no active connections to database before you execute this query. And you have to execute this query only once and it will start using Snapshot Isolation. You will have to explicitly turn it off , if you ever want to revert it back.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the isolation level is pretty simple:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

However, you need to **really, really** make sure you are aware of the consequence of the different isolation levels.  I'd suggest this [Brent Ozar (by Kendra Little)](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) article as a starting point.

Comment: Brent Ozar is a GREAT resource on all things DBA